# Slurm job submit plugin

Tags: slurm

I installed Slurm using DeepOps, and I encountered a problem while setting up the **job_submit** plugin.

I followed the instructions provided in the documentation and various resources as follows:

1. Added `JobSubmitPlugins=lua` to `Slurm.conf`.
2. Retrieved the `job_submit.lua` file from the **GitHub Slurm repository** and placed it in `/etc/slurm`.
3. Executed `systemctl restart slurmctld`.

Despite following these steps, `slurmctld` did not start, and I found the following logs.

```
[2023-05-18T06:49:14.643] error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for job_submit/lua looking at all files
[2023-05-18T06:49:14.644] error: cannot find job_submit plugin for job_submit/lua
[2023-05-18T06:49:14.644] error: cannot create job_submit context for job_submit/lua
[2023-05-18T06:49:14.644] fatal: failed to initialize job_submit plugin

fix slurm.conf
slurmctld restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Slurm was compiled with Lua support. For that, the Lua "devel" packages from your distribution must be installed on the server on which Slurm is compiled before compiling or creating an RPM.